# How to create a histogram for the given DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following DataFrame `df` (a small extract is given):

```
time_diff   avg_qty_per_day
1.450000    1.0
1.483333    1.0
1.500000    1.0
2.516667    1.0
2.533333    1.0
2.533333    1.5
3.633333    1.8
3.644567    5.0
```

I want to create the histogram for variable `time_diff` in order to see how its values are distributed and which values have the highest frequency.

I do it using this code:

```
bins = np.arange(df['time_diff'].min(), df['time_diff'].max()+1, 1)
hist, edges = np.histogram(df['time_diff'], bins=bins)

norm = plt.Normalize(hist.min(), hist.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(hist)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
ax.bar(edges[:-1], hist, np.diff(edges), color=colors, ec="k")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize=11)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['time_diff']), max(df['time_diff'])+1, 1.0))
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,p: locale.format('%d', x, 1)))
plt.show()
```

The problem is that this code does not consider the values of `avg_qty_per_day` in order to calculate the frequency of `time_diff` (Y axis). It just counts each row as 1 occurrence. However, I need to use `avg_qty_per_day` as the number of occurrences.
How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

For example, if I do this:

```
a = df[df.time_diff>3]
np.sum(a.avg_trips_per_day.values)
```

..., then I get the answer `6.8`. It does not coincide with Y axis in my plot, where I have `2` for the corresponding bin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first to group by "time_diff" taking the sum of "avg_qty_per_day".
Here is a dummy code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
print(df.head())
df.groupby("A").sum()
plt.hist(df.A)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand how `hist` considers `B` if I just say `plt.hist(df.A)`

Comment: Also, in my case I would need to group data into bins, e.g. 0-5, 5-10, etc. How can I do it and sum up values of `avg_qty_per_day`?

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct way. But why not create a column called "bin" and group by this column?